# What is the difference between using First..Last and 1..count in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql, data-collection

What is the difference between using `First..Last` and `1..count` in Oracle?

```
FOR i IN l_collection.FIRST..l_collection.LAST LOOP
```

or

```
FOR i IN 1..l_collection.COUNT LOOP
```

Comment: If you create an index by table, and you have your index starting by 1, there's no difference. But you can create a collection by some other value. That way, would be better to use first.. last

Answer (score 6):

`first` and `last` returns the first index and last index. `count` returns the number of elements in the collection. These do not necessarily give a correct way of referencing the elements in the collection, as you can have sparse collections, where index values are not contiguous (see below example).

```
declare
  type t_numbers is table of number index by pls_integer;
  l_numbers t_numbers;
begin
  l_numbers(1) := 5;
  l_numbers(4) := 6;
  for i in l_numbers.first..l_numbers.last loop
    dbms_output.put_line(i);
  end loop;
end;
/

1
2
3
4

declare
  type t_numbers is table of number index by pls_integer;
  l_numbers t_numbers;
begin
  l_numbers(1) := 5;
  l_numbers(4) := 6;
  for i in 1..l_numbers.count loop
    dbms_output.put_line(i);
  end loop;
end;
/

1
2
```

I hope you see why both versions fail. These work properly only as long as you have dense collections (where index values are contiguous). With sparse collections, both method fail, and you should use a `WHILE` loop:

```
declare
  type t_numbers is table of number index by pls_integer;
  l_index number;
  l_numbers t_numbers;
begin
  l_numbers(1) := 5;
  l_numbers(4) := 6;
  l_index := l_numbers.first;
  while (l_index is not null)
  loop
    dbms_output.put_line(l_index);
    l_index := l_numbers.next(l_index);
  end loop;
end;
/

1
4
```